# matrix3d in webkit-transform and moz-transform render different outputs

Tags: css, transform

Hi I've tried using matrix3d to transform figure 1.
Finally, figure 2 (-moz-transform) is what I wanted and got when run the below code in Firefox 43.0, comparing figure 3 (-webkit-transform) rendered by Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit).

[Figure 1-2-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiDOE.jpg)

```
<style>
  #transform{
    transform:         matrix3d(-0.000118252, 0.403212, 0, -0.00000128535, -0.81433, -0.209, 0, -0.000405756, 0, 0, 1, 0, 869, 209, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.000118252, 0.403212, 0, -0.00000128535, -0.81433, -0.209, 0, -0.000405756, 0, 0, 1, 0, 869, 209, 0, 1);
    -moz-transform:    matrix3d(-0.000118252, 0.403212, 0, -0.00000128535, -0.81433, -0.209, 0, -0.000405756, 0, 0, 1, 0, 869, 209, 0, 1);
  }
</style>
<svg id="transform" width="1000" height="1000" style="transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;">
    <g transform="translate(0,0)">
      <image xlink:href="test_tile.jpg" width="1000" height="1000">
    </g>
</svg>
```

I'm wondering whether it's a bug in Chrome or did I do anything wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I believe it's due to the way transforms are handled differently by FF & Chrome for SVG. If you search SO...you'll find a number of questions on this.

Comment: I've tried Safari on MacOS behaves in the same way with Chrome in Ubuntu; however, Opera, Chrome in Windows giving the same output as Firefox in Ubuntu did. I believe webkit-transfrom might be implemented in different way.